# Azure Table Storage Create or Update in single operation

Tags: azure-table-storage

Is it possible to create or update an entity in Azure Table Storage in a single operation or do I have to perform multiple steps?

First, a `READ` to see if the entity already exists and if not, I'll perform the second operation which will be a `REPLACE`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your needs, I suggest you using `insertOrReplace` method in `azure table storage SDK`.

I don't know what language you're using currently. I just provide `Java SDK` as a reference.

```
try
{
    // Retrieve storage account from connection-string.
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount =
        CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);

    // Create the table client.
    CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.createCloudTableClient();

    // Create a cloud table object for the table.
    CloudTable cloudTable = tableClient.getTableReference("people");

    // Create a new customer entity.
    CustomerEntity customer1 = new CustomerEntity("Harp", "Walter");
    customer1.setEmail("Walter@contoso.com");
    customer1.setPhoneNumber("425-555-0101");

    // Create an operation to add the new customer to the people table.
    TableOperation insertCustomer1 = TableOperation.insertOrReplace(customer1);

    // Submit the operation to the table service.
    cloudTable.execute(insertCustomer1);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // Output the stack trace.
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

> TableOperation insertCustomer1 =
>   TableOperation.insertOrReplace(customer1);

You could also refer to the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-how-to-use-java).

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you! Do I not need to concern myself with ETag?

Comment: @Sam Please refer to this link: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/managing-concurrency-in-microsoft-azure-storage-2/

Comment: Very useful article! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it should be [InsertOrReplace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/insert-or-replace-entity) operation.